How to share a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime between multiple Azure Synapse Workspaces?
I have a test and prod Synapse Workspace, and I want to be able to use the same self-hosted integration runtime in both, yet there does not appear to be an option to do so like there is in ADF?
Am I expected to use two different SHIRs? If so, how would I deploy changes from test to prod via CI/CD when the runtimes would be different.
What are my options?
I've tried setting up a SHIR in one environment and the share option is not available.
